# Have Danish authorities made public the scope of their investigation into the Nord Stream sabotage?

Tags: denmark, nord-stream, investigation

The initial reason(s) invoked by German federal prosecutors in opening an investigation into the Nord Stream sabotage were [that](https://www.dw.com/en/germany-launches-probe-into-suspected-nord-stream-sabotage/a-63397922)

> Federal prosecutors are investigating "persons unknown" suspected of ["anti-constitutional sabotage"](https://www.lewik.org/term/15505/sabotage-against-the-constitution-section-88-german-criminal-code/) on the pipelines as well as "deliberately causing an explosion." [...]
>
> Germany's federal prosecutor's office usually only opens probes into cases that concern national security, such as terror attacks.
>
> The office said its involvement in the pipeline leaks was justified in that a "violent attack on the energy supply could impact the external and internal security" of Germany, a spokesperson told news agency AFP.

So the [rationale for the] German probe does not actually depend on whether the attack was carried out from German soil (but it [turned out](https://www.dw.com/en/nord-stream-investigators-find-traces-of-explosives-on-yacht/a-66196447) that that probably happened as well.)

Clearly the Swedish interest was not as broad/deep, given their [stated reasons](https://www.aklagare.se/en/media/press-releases/2024/february/the-prosecutor-closes-the-swedish-investigation-concerning-gross-sabotage-against-nord-stream/) for dropping/ending their prosecutor's investigation:

> the primary purpose of the investigation has been to establish whether Swedish citizens were involved in the act and whether Swedish territory was used to carry out the act [...]

The Danish probe appears to be conducted by police and intelligence services, rather than a prosecutor, but I could be mistaken. Anyway, **have the relevant Danish authorities (that are conducting their investigation[s]) said what is the scope of the Danish investigation?** (I.e. is it more limited like Sweden's, relating to means or persons, or do they broadly charge that Danish interests are at stake, like Germany did. [Yes, I'm aware the pipelines end in Germany, not Denmark.])

Comment: The most dangerous thing in any investigation is a possibility of the prove self guilt involvement. So, better to stop it promptly. But that is a precedent of industrial terrorism "legality"

Answer (score 1):

A week later we know. It [was](https://www.france24.com/en/europe/20240226-denmark-closes-investigation-into-2022-nord-stream-pipeline-sabotage) apparently similar in scope to Sweden's, and is now closed:

> "Based on the investigation, the authorities can conclude that the sabotage of the pipelines was intentional," Copenhagen police said in a statement.
>
> "At the same time, it is also assessed that **there is not the necessary basis for pursuing a criminal case in Denmark**," it said.
>
> [...] Copenhagen police said that the investigation -- which had been carried out together with Denmark's intelligence service PET -- had been "complicated and extensive."
>
> It added that it was not in a position to "provide further comments" in the case.
>
> [...] The decision to close the Danish investigation was immediately criticised by Russia.